# Stop loop and continue from stopping point

Tags: php, loops

**problem Solved..... thanks alot**

I want to break the loop and continue loop from the point that the loop stop. E.g., if I have array like this:

```
$arr = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5');
```

I want to stop looping on number '3' and take an action and continue from '4'. I tried this code:

```
$x = 0;
foreach($arr as $key){
    if($x == 3) break; // here I stop loop in number 3 
    echo $key;

    $x++;
    // I want to continue loop from 4
}
```

Comment: first, 'foreach' loops are not 'restartable'. To do what you require you need to look at the 'state' pattern. Think of it as a custom 'iterator' where you implement all the required routines for the 'iterator' interface. It can get very 'interesting' with other structures which have their own 'state' i.e files, however if  you stick with arrays then it really is quite useful.

Comment: my friend Ryan iam beginner in php what is  'state' pattern mean ???

Comment: Look, PHP provides the 'primitives' for traversing arrays. See the 'reset', 'first', next' 'current' functions. It is easy to make 'restartable' scans of arrays. I suggest that you search for 'php iterator next tutorial' or something similar in your favourite search engine. 'restartable' means --> continue from where you left off.

Comment: Oh, there is nothing wrong with the problem you asked. There are lots of problems that require what you want. There are a lot easier ways of solving it than with a 'foreach' loop.

Comment: ok can you advice me one solution :)

Comment: There are people who have already provided solutions. I suggest you edit your question to provide ALL the information as to what you want to do! Include the reason why you wanted to stop the loop at 3 and restart it later. They are really bright people, who want to help, and find 'programming' fun, as do i, and will provide useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

why stop?

use

```
$x = 0;

foreach($arr as $key){

  if($x == 3) 
     doSomething();
  else
     echo $key;

  $x++;
}
```

it will continue with iteration 4, after "doing Something". (Correctly spoken: It will iterate from 1 to n, and only perform an action, when `$x==3`, otherwhise print the key.)

If you just want to avoid key "3" beeing printed, you can use the `continue` statement:

```
$x = 0;

foreach($arr as $key){

  if($x++ == 3) 
     continue; //proceed with next iteration

  echo $key;
}
```

but then you need to use `$x++` in your comparrision, otherwhise it will get stuck at `$x==3`, cause the increment will always be skipped.

Sidenode: If you NEED `$x` to be the correct line number, use a `for()` instead of `foreach()` - use `foreach()`, if you dont care about the actual line number, but need to process ALL entries within an array.

Sidenode 2: `foreach($arr as $key)` is **wrong**. This expression will give you the **value** for each array entry, not the **key**. use `foreach($arr as $key=>$value)` or `foreach($arr as $value)` to have a correct name on the variable(s).

Comment: but i want to continue echo the '4' and '5'

Comment: i want echo '1', '2', '3' and stop and do an action like echo 'good'
and then echo '4', '5' and do another action like echo 'good2'